# Rounding the numeric values in a dplyr tbl_df upon printing

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to keep the true values in a dplyr table (tbl_df) but display rounded versions. I feel like there must be a printing method argument to do this.

Here's an example of what I want:

```
my_tbl <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_each(funs((sum(.*12345e20))))
```

Instead of this:

```
print(my_tbl)
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

     Species Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width
      (fctr)        (dbl)        (dbl)        (dbl)        (dbl)
1     setosa 3.089954e+26 2.115933e+26 9.024195e+25 1.518435e+25
2 versicolor 3.663996e+26 1.709783e+26 2.629485e+26 8.184735e+25
3  virginica 4.066443e+26 1.835702e+26 3.426972e+26 1.250549e+26
```

I want something like

```
print(my_tbl, signif=3)
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
      (fctr)        (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)
1     setosa     3.09e+26    2.12e+26     9.02e+25    1.52e+25
2 versicolor     3.66e+26    1.71e+26     2.63e+26    8.18e+25
3  virginica     4.07e+26    1.84e+26     3.43e+26    1.25e+26
```

Comment: What do you mean by "real values"?

Comment: Have clarified the question. I don't mean real in the mathematical sense. I want to create a data table then print to 3 s.f. without altering the values in the table.

Comment: Would downvoters mind reviewing the question and clarifying their reason for the downvote given the rewording.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could rewrite `dplyr:::print.tbl_df` to include a `signif` argument.

```
print.tbl_df <- function (x, ..., signif = 3, n = NULL, width = NULL) 
{
    nums <- vapply(x, is.numeric, NA)
    x[nums] <- lapply(x[nums], signif, digits = signif)
    cat("Source: local data frame ", dim_desc(x), "\n", sep = "")
    cat("\n")
    print(trunc_mat(x, n = n, width = width))
    invisible(x)
}

my_tbl <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_each(funs((sum(.*12345e20))))
```

Now any `tbl_df` prints with the default significant digits of 3.

```
my_tbl
# Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#
#      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#       (fctr)        (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)
# 1     setosa     3.09e+26    2.12e+26     9.02e+25    1.52e+25
# 2 versicolor     3.66e+26    1.71e+26     2.63e+26    8.18e+25
# 3  virginica     4.07e+26    1.84e+26     3.43e+26    1.25e+26
```

To print with other significant digits, we can use `print()`.

```
print(my_tbl, signif = 5)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#
#      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#       (fctr)        (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)
# 1     setosa   3.0900e+26  2.1159e+26   9.0242e+25  1.5184e+25
# 2 versicolor   3.6640e+26  1.7098e+26   2.6295e+26  8.1847e+25
# 3  virginica   4.0664e+26  1.8357e+26   3.4270e+26  1.2505e+26
```

Comment: more elegant could be just use `format` on `2:5` columns just before the print, so they would be character type but still it is just a print.

Comment: @jangorecki - the only problem there is that the column classes become "AsIs" and they are shown in the output.

Answer (score 8):

Use `print.data.frame` instead of `print` after adjusting the digits `option`.

```
options(digits = 3)
print.data.frame(my_tbl)

    Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
     setosa     3.09e+26    2.12e+26     9.02e+25    1.52e+25
 versicolor     3.66e+26    1.71e+26     2.63e+26    8.18e+25
  virginica     4.07e+26    1.84e+26     3.43e+26    1.25e+26
```

Comment: You could also do `print.data.frame(my_tbl, digits = 3)` without having to change any options.