# Undesirable behaviour - as.double rounds the decimals

Tags: r, dplyr, double, decimal

I've got following data:

```
ex <- structure(list(X1 = c("0", "2912.99", "922.1", "772.9100000000001", 
"7112.97", "933.09", "1190.03")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .Names = "X1", class = 
c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To my surprise, when I'm trying to convert them to `double`, decimals are rounded up to integers.

```
ex %>% mutate(X1 = as.double(X1))
```

I have tried to change the digits options with `options(digits = 22)`, but it didn't help. What causes this problem? Is it a matter of using `dplyr::mutate`? How this can be alternatively converted to `double`?

Comment: The appearance might seem to be integers but they are actually double and not integers. Its just that the tibble view shows it so. you can try `ex %>% mutate(X1 = as.double(X1))%>%data.frame()` and you will see that indeed they are decimals

Comment: Well, so the issue is connected with usage of `tibble`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding the numeric values in a dplyr tbl\_df upon printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246552/rounding-the-numeric-values-in-a-dplyr-tbl-df-upon-printing)

Answer (score 0):

One may choose the number of digits printed by setting the option
of the [pillar package](http://pillar.r-lib.org/reference/pillar-package.html#package-options), which is used by `tibble`.

```
> options(pillar.sigfig=16)
> ex %>% mutate(X1 = as.double(X1))
# A tibble: 7 x 1
                   X1
                <dbl>
1     0.             
2  2912.990000000000 
3   922.1000000000000
4   772.9100000000001
5  7112.970000000000 
6   933.0900000000000
7  1190.030000000000
```

Comment: Lol, great timing, but be aware you need to adjust `options(digits = 22)` as well. Only `options(pillar.sigfig=22)` is not gonna do it.

Comment: Haha, thanks. Actually for `tibble` the `pillar.sigfig` is enough (for me the code works even with `options(digits = 0)`.

Comment: Interesting, for me it does not. :P

Comment: @Len Even more interesting, for me neither of your codes work. Still prints as it would be integers.

Comment: Sorry, noticed now there was a typo in my code. You could try again now. :)

Comment: my versions: `pillar`: 1.2.1, `tibble`: 1.4.2

Comment: This doesnt work for me either. Is there any update to this solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want tibbles to be printed with more than 3 decimals as a default, you need to adjust the pillar.sigfig option as well:

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 22)
options(digits = 22)

ex %>% mutate(X1 = as.double(X1))

                   X1
                <dbl>
1    0.00000000000000
2 2912.98999999999978
3  922.10000000000002
4  772.91000000000008
5 7112.97000000000025
6  933.09000000000003
7 1190.02999999999997
```